# How to use image in IRandomAccessStreamReference for Shape.Fill

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have an image stored as IRandomAccessStreamReference which I need to use as the fill in an Ellipse.  How would I go about using this?

```
...
 static IRandomAccessStreamReference myThumbnail;
...
 var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
 var contact = await contactStore.GetMeContactAsync();
 myThumbnail = contact.Thumbnail;
...
 Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse
            {

                Height = 32,
                Width = 32,
                Fill = myThumbnail, // How do I use this?
             };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to use `ImageBrush` class, which derived from base `Brush` class.
This class contains `ImageSource` property, base class for `BitmapImage`. Also, for instance of `BitmapImage` class, I suggest use `DecodePixelWidth` or `DecodePixelHeight` property.

```
var thumbailImageBrush = new ImageBrush();
using (var randomStream = await myThumbnail.OpenReadAsync())
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 32; // just good practice
    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(randomStream);
    thumbailImageBrush.ImageSource = bitmapImage;
}

var ellipse = new Ellipse
{
    Height = 32,
    Width = 32,
    Fill = thumbailImageBrush
};
```